# What do the permissions mean in /proc/<pid>/fd/?

Tags: permissions, symlink, proc, file-descriptors

I'm looking at the result of running `ls -l` on `/proc/<pid>/fd/`:

```
lr-x------ 1 root root 64 Apr 22 23:13 0 -> /dev/null
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 Apr 22 23:13 1 -> 'socket:[19700]'
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 Apr 22 23:13 2 -> 'socket:[19700]'
...
```

What do the permissions mean on the symlinks?  The first thing that occurs to me is that they represent the "mode" of the file descriptors.  However, if that is indeed the case, why would `stdout` be readable?  Furthermore, why would all of the descriptors be executable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Linux' `/proc` filesystem presents objects which are actually not files as files: it's using a known API to present objects as files.

For the file descriptors, there is no actual symlink existing. But a symlink is a convenient way to present information about the file descriptor. Such symlink is created on-the-fly when needed (and might possibly stay cached in the VFS so they will usually have the date of the first time they were displayed). Usually on Linux symlinks are always having all possible allowed rights because it's their targed which is validated instead. But here, the rights are presented to reflect the way the file descriptor was opened. They are presented as owned by the user (or sometimes root when for example the process is set as non-dumpable or non-ptracable) and limited to user access attributes even if the access attributes are not really checked (the ownership check *is* enforced, see below). Many details are documented in [`proc(5)`](https://manpages.debian.org/manpages/proc.5#Files_and_directories) at the `/proc/[pid]/fd/` entry for example:

> /proc/[pid]/fd/
>
> [...]
>
> For file descriptors for pipes and sockets, the entries will be
> symbolic links whose content is the file type with the inode. A
> readlink(2) call on this file returns a string in the format:
>
> type:[inode]
>
> [...]
>
> Permission to dereference or read (readlink(2)) the symbolic links in
> this directory is governed by a ptrace access mode
> `PTRACE_MODE_READ_FSCREDS` check; see ptrace(2).

so one can check only process belonging to the same user (or not even, if process is set as non-dumpable/non-ptracable and other special caveats).

What I didn't manage to find documented in `proc(5)` is that usually the access rights presented on the symlinks for `proc/[pid]/fd/` reflect the way the file descriptor was opened. So opening read-only (`ls -l /proc/self/fd/9 9</dev/null`), write-only (`ls -l /proc/self/fd/9 9>/dev/null`) or read-write (`ls -l /proc/self/fd/9 9<>/dev/null`) will respectively be displayed with these access rights:

```
lr-x------
l-wx------
lrwx------
```

Likewise, (non-named) pipes created with `pipe(2)` will have one FD in read mode and one in write mode. Sockets are bidirectional: there's no notion of "opening" them read-only or write-only, actually there's never an `open(2)` system-call for them. They will be seen as `lrwx------` to reflect they can be read or written to.

Answer (score 2):

man chmod(1) says:

> chmod never changes the permissions of symbolic links; the chmod system call cannot change their permissions. **This is not a problem since the permissions of symbolic links are never used.** However, for each symbolic link listed on the command line, chmod changes the permissions of the pointed-to file.

They basically mean nothing.

Comment: But in `/proc` each file can lie and not follow what's standard: there is no actual symbolic link, but a symbolic link is presented to have a known API to represent the FD. OP's stdout is readable because it's the same bidirectional socket.